# GeoServer 2.21 SLD - how to make complex text-based label

Tags: geoserver, sld

Can I create the "Label" like in the picture below and apply it to the "Layer" using the SLD?

![image: Picture Link]

Source site for picture : https://sdimd-free.austrocontrol.at/mapstore/#/viewer/openlayers/121

Comment: what have you tried so far? what isn't working for you?

Comment: @IanTurton, thanks for the reply. I can do some basic labeling and styling using SDL, but can't find a way how to do this type of complex labeling. Maybe some kind of examples will help me to come up with a solution.

Comment: If you [edit] your question to show where you have got to and what isn't working, we can give you some help. But stackexchange isn't here to do your job/homework for you

Comment: @IanTurton, I understand it very well. I'm asking for tips that will help me find an actual solution. It might be some examples, docs, books, articles, and so on. I just can't find any real examples. Right now, the official docs are not enough for me for creating such complex labels. Thanks for your time